# C++ Macro with "double function"

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I am looking for a way to use a single macro call (multiple times):

```c
#define MAGIC  ???????

MAGIC(ref1, "text 1");
MAGIC(ref2, "text 2");
```

to expand into something like this:

```c
const char *texts[] = {"text 1", "text 2"};
enum {ref1, ref2}
```

I got two ways of create first line:

```c
#define _COUNT(z, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, count, ...) count
#define COUNT(...) _COUNT(0, ##__VA_ARGS__, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)

#define EVENTS(...)                                           \
    const struct                                              \
    {                                                         \
        int n = COUNT(__VA_ARGS__);                           \
        const char *texts[COUNT(__VA_ARGS__)] = {__VA_ARGS__}; \
    }

EVENTS("text 1", "text 2", "text N");
```

and:

```c
#define BEGIN(n) \
    const struct        \
    {                   \
        int cnt = (n);  \
        const char *texts[(n) + 1] = {

#define EVENT(id, text) text,

#define END \
    0              \
    }              \
    ;              \
    }              \
    ;

BEGIN(2)
EVENT(ref1, "text 1")
EVENT(ref2, "text 2")
END
```

both will work to create the fist line. However the first not even include the reference name and the second one ignores it.

I am sure I can create de second line as well, but how to create both at the same time?

I have hundreds of pairs like this to declare in a more complex code, and hope this will improve reading.

Any way to do it using GCC?

Comment: You want reflective enumerations, right? https://github.com/quicknir/wise_enum

Comment: Setting aside the propriety of macros, macros can't do everything. Using the right tool for the right job is always the best solution: put this into a separate file, in some parsable format like XML or YAML. Use any one of many freely available tools to write a script to translate it into C++ code and write it out to a header file. Integrate the whole thing in your build framework. Mission accomplished.  Been there, done that many times.

Comment: _Setting aside the propriety of macros_ that was very restrained of you, @sam.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I though... was in hope to someone to indroduce me to some way to do it tho, but looks like macros are really limited. @SamVarshavchik, like your aproach... will investigate it, thanks!

Comment: `_COUNT` is a reserved identifier since it starts with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter. You should not define it as a macro or otherwise. (Technically results in undefined behavior.)

Comment: _put this into a separate file, in some parsable format like XML or YAML_ If the data you want to process is really as simple as in your example, I would just put it in a text file.  It would be easy to parse with `awk`, and `awk` is very easy to learn.  I actually mostly use [GNU awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), but for what you want to use it for, the documentation for that probably applies equally well to the version of `awk` that's built in to Linux.

Comment: You cannot call the macro as `SUPERMAGIC(ref1, "text 1", ref2, "text 2");`, can you? Or as `SUPERMAGIC(MAGIC(ref1, "text 1"), MAGIC(ref2, "text 2"));`? Are those values pairs or  an arbitrary amount?

Comment: Perhaps Boost Preprocessor (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) gives you some inspiration?

Answer (score 1):

> how to create both at the same time?

It is not possible - macros have no "state" that they can "set" from inside a macro expansion. You can't remember that you have seen some macro invocation and act on it later.

What you are (re-)implementing are [X macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro), where you use the *same file* with a different macro twice, solving the problem with remembering state. "State" depends on the location in the file, where you can change the macro definition.

```
// file_with_magic.h
MAGIC(ref1, "text 1")
MAGIC(ref2, "text 2")

// header.h
const char *texts[] = {
#define MAGIC(a, b)  b
#include <file_with_magic.h>
#undef MAGIC
};
enum {
#define MAGIC(a, b)  a
#include <file_with_magic.h>
#undef MAGIC
};
```